# Buttons within View Pager

Tags: java, android, button, android-viewpager

I am trying to add buttons within a Fragment of PageView.

Please find attached the code that I am using for this application:

The specific code for the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/banner_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_banner"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/equations"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollViewEquations"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:textColor="#516CE2"
                android:text="@string/button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout
```

this is the associated fragment code

```
package com.example.app;

import com.example.app![enter image description here][1].R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class EquationsMain extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.equations, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is the main code:

```
package com.example.app;

import com.example.app.R;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); 

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new EquationsMain();
            case 1:
                return new MaterialsMain();
            case 2:
                return new AboutMain();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add a button in one of the fragments which opens a new page

Comment: Yes, I got that, but what is the problem? =)

Comment: Am I am quite new to android I do not know where to place the button in the class files

Comment: public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
       
   View equationsButton=findViewById(R.id.equations_button);
  equationsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

     }

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.equations_button:
   Intent i=new Intent(this, Equations.class);
   startActivity(i);
  }
 }
 
}

Comment: I have no idea where to place the code that I have used before